# Nested iframe jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an youtube video iframe on a page here -- http://viibe.tv/testingtime/index2.html

The video pauses when you scroll vertical (when video is not on screen), and starts playing again when video comes on screen. So its working perfectly fine on this page.

There is another case where the same video is coming on page, but through another embed iframe -- http://viibe.tv/testingtime/index.html

And the pause/play on scroll doesn't seems to work on this page. Have tried all solutions, but it doesn't get fixed. Please see if someone can be of any help or guide me in the right direction.

**jquery.visible** is used for tracking visibility of iframe on screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the embedded video is directly from youtube.

In second example , the source is different.

Try this link for the second example.
https://www.youtube.com/embed/2q2CMHjNWCE?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1

I think that was the problem.